# Where is Query.Eq located in mongo driver classes?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to follow examples of mongodo driver code in C#, and my editor is not providing me with the Query class ( to do Query.Eq), what do I need to include so this works in the intellisense. I have mongodb.bson, mongodb.driver, and mongodb.driver.core added to the project.

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The static Query class is located in the MongoDB.Driver.Legacy library (mongocsharpdriver nuget package). If you are just starting out, then you should use that and instead use the Builders.Filter class, which is used throughout the API in >=2.0.

Comment: ok thanks, I dont want the legacy stuff added to the project. So I should ignore all examples using the Query class and use the Builders instead? I have come across a lot of examples using Builders.

Comment: Yes. use the Builders. It is the new API.